# Pulling variable out of NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I have a fit,

```
Dynamic[f1 = NonlinearModelFit[d1, a Exp[-(b (x - c1))^2] + yoff, {a, b}, x]]
```

Where I need to be able to access `b` at a later point in the code.

However, if I run `Dynamic[b]`, `b` is undefined after running the fit.

How can I extract `b`?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` will produce a `FittedModel`; to extract the equation as an expression, use `Normal`.

Comment: 1) Unless you have other definitions in place that you are not showing us, your `NonlinearModelFit` is probably not going to work as written: you should have `c1` and `yoff` listed as parameters as well. 2) `NonlinearModelFit` will not assign a value to fit parameters, so the described behavior is what you would expect anyway, and it doesn't depend on the presence of Dynamic. Once you get the fitting to work, you can extract the value of `b` from `f1` using e.g. `b /. f1["BestFitParameters"]`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to bother with `Dynamic` for what you want to do. Consider the following, which uses a different model because you did not provide a sufficient information for me to use the one you are reefer to in your post.

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x]
```

> ```
> FittedModel[
>    {"Nonlinear", {a -> 1.5063204891556878, b -> 1.4263297975161129}, 
>      {{x}, Log[a + b*x^2]}}, 
>    {1}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}}, 
>    Function[Null, Internal`LocalizedBlock[{a, b, x}, #1], {HoldAll}]]
> ```

The above shows the fit object returned by `NonlinearModelFit` stores parameters of the fit. You can extract the parameters at any time from the fit object with

```
 fit[[1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {a -> 1.50632, b -> 1.42633}
> ```

or by the more convenient

```
 fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

> ```
> {a -> 1.50632, b -> 1.42633}
> ```